# UITableView load cells reverse

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to make my cell load and use it's data in reverse. Basically, I want the last cell to be the first.

Answer (score 15):

Do you mean you want to display your data from rail to head?
Maybe you should perform it at your table's data source method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...
  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  NSUInteger count = [listData count]; // here listData is your data source
  cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:(count-row-1)];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be (count-1-row).

Comment: This will be accessing the opposite number in the data?

Comment: I think so. If you use NSArray or its subclass to hold your data source. And also you can use 'reverseObjectEnumerator'. If you use other kind of data structures to hold your data, you need to use a corresponding 'reverse' accessing method.

Comment: (count-1-row) and (count-row-1) isn't that the same? it's like (10 - 1 - 4) and (10 - 4 - 1) that would both give the difference of 5.

Comment: Perfect solution - simple and effective